# If condition in lodash template

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm having an issue evaluating an if condition inside the template function of lodash.

When running this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  evaluate: /\{\{([^#].*?)\}\}/g,
  interpolate: /\{\{([^#].*?)\}\}/g,
  escape: /\{\{\{(.+?)\}\}\}/g
};

eventsInfoTemplate = _.template(
  '<div class="list-item" data-id="{{events.event_id}}">' +
    '<div class="list-info">' +
      '<div class="list-info__venue">' +
        '<h5 class="event-title">' +
          '<a href="#">{{events.event_name}}' +
            '{{# if (events.event_type != "Performance") { }}'
              '<span class="event-type__badge">{{events.event_type}}</span>'
            '{{# } }}'
          '</a>' +
        '</h5>' +
        '<span class="event-details">{{events.event_date}} | {{events.event_venue}}</span>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>' 
)({events: {}});
```

It returns everything inside the if condition as an element.  When removing the `+` from the if condition then it returns an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or can you not put an `if` condition inside the template?

Comment: Are you using both [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)? Try just writing `events.event_type` instead of `{{events.event_type}}`.

Comment: I've added templateSettings to use handlebars style `_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};`  But as per your request I removed the braces and it is still returning the same error.  If I put the `+` after each line it is treating it like a string

Comment: Ah, shoot. Then I don't know :( Hopefully a pro can chime in.

Comment: Try to remove interpolation inside "if", if ({{events.event_type}} here interpolation isn't required, because it will insert value once you execute template function. (_.template(<your template string>)({events: {}}));

Now it counts "{{" as javascript code.

Comment: Thanks I tried that as well and still receiving the same error as stated above using this `<% if (events.event_type != "Performance") { %>'
                    '<span class="event-type__badge">{{events.event_type}}</span>' +
                  '<% } %>'`

Comment: You returned "+" to if condition? I've tried removing interpolation with string provided in your question. It executes well.

Comment: I've updated original code with what I currently have based off your suggestions.  That code is still returning an error, am I missing something?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yty5ua5k/1/. But when I add your template settings, it treats if condition as a string. I've tried to debug it on jsfiddle. It appears that it uses just your interpolation regex, and not mixes default escape and evaluate regexes when building "reDelimiters" regex. Try to provide evaluate regex as well or use defaut delimiters.

Comment: I followed your jsfiddle and that works fine, I'll just not use custom interpolation right now.  Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mu6rx1L8/ another jsfiddle with custom interpolation. But this {{# }} stands for interpolation and this {{ }} for evaluation. The reason why it is vise versa, because lodash and underscore process interpolation regex first and then only evaluate regex. So evaluate can't be extended from interpolate.

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense.  Thank you so much and this works great.  I appreciate all your help!  If you want to submit an answer I'll mark it as the answer.